# How to get a c# variable (string) value in the .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptlet

So with this code.

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {

        public string feedbackPostback = "false";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How to I access `feebackPostback` from:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
            tabHandle: '.handle',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
            pathToTabImage: 'images/feedback.gif',    //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
            imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
            imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
            tabLocation: 'right',                     //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
            speed: 300,                               //speed of animation
            action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
            topPos: '150px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
            leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
            fixedPosition: false,                      //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
            onLoadSlideOut: <%= this.feebackPostback %>
        });

    });
</script>
```

Currently trying `<%= this.feebackPostback %>` and returns this error: CS1061: 'ASP.site_master' does not contain a definition for 'feebackPostback' and no extension method 'feebackPostback' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.site_master' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: for one, it's spelled differently in its declaration and in its usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled `feedbackPostback`—you forgot the `d`.